# Permutation Combination question (3*n board)

Tags: math, combinations, permutation, probability

I have a question:
Find the total number of ways a 3×n board can be painted using 3 colors while making sure no cells of the same row or the same column have entirely the same color. The answer must be computed modulo 10^9+7.

Also somebody answered it here.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215805/coloring-a-3-times-n-board-using-3-colors

but i am not able to understand, can you explain in easy language?

Comment: The linked answer looks quite clear, it starts by only looking at the columns, seeing that only 24 colorings are possible per column, then subtracts the solutions with at least one monochrome row, adds back in the solutions with at least two monochrome rows and finally subracts the 24 solutions with 3 monochrome rows. By the way, what do you mean by `modulo 109+7`? Isn't that just an unnecessary detail? And confusing in either being `(modulo 109)+7` or `modulo (109+7)`?

Comment: Sorry, it was actually 10^9 + 7, my bad. Still, I am not getting the solution, can you please explain two and one mono. row thing with an example or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the general principle, let's look at a situation with only two columns. Name the colors red, green and blue.

For a column to fulfill the conditions: Each cell can have one of 3 colors, there are 3 cells, totaling 3^3=27 possible colorings. Among these, 3 are monochrome (one red, one green, one blue). Subtracting the disallowed colorings: 27-3=24 possibilities for a column. Only considering the columns, there are 24^n colorings for the board.

Now, let's look at the disallowed rows. For the monochrome row, there are 3 colors and 3 possible rows to choose from. For each of these 9 possibilities, each column can be colored in 8 possible ways. This means 9x8^n rows need to be removed. The image below shows each of the possible boards where no column is monochrome. The 9x8^2=576 rows to be removed are shown with a black line:

[image]

If we now subtract the number of blacked out rows from the total, we are subtracting too many: some boards have two bad rows and some even three.

So, the count of the boards with two bad rows has to be added again. Their total is 3x3x2^n + 3x6x3^n. The first term counts the case with two equal colored bad rows: 3 positions for the non-bad row, 3 colors for the bad rows, 2 remaining colors for each cell of the non-bad row. The second term counts the case with two differently colored bad rows: 3 positions for the non-bad row, 6 possible colorings for the bad rows, 3 possible colors for each cell of the non-bad row.

There are 24 boards with three bad rows which got subtracted three times in the second step and added again three times in the third step. They now have to be subtracted from the total.

So, as explained in [the linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215805/coloring-a-3-times-n-board-using-3-colors), the general formula is:

```
24^n − 9×8^n + 18×3^n+9×2^n − 24
```

which gives the values `0, 174, 9750, 296490, 7672350, 188757354, 4567637550, 109924439610, 2640599939550, 63393718361034, ...` for n starting at 1.

Or modulo 10^9+7:

```
0, 174, 9750, 296490, 7672350, 188757354, 567637522, 924438847, 599921070, 717917283, ...
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Beautiful answer.